# Проверка синтаксиса PHP

Tags: php

Может кто знает программу, где есть проверка синтаксиса (не подсветка, а именно проверка). Что-то вроде Zend Studio (не работает она у меня). Есть PHPEditor, но при проверке он ошибку выдает, что не может найти php.exe. Перелопатил все настройки, все указал, но он сбрасывает их и - ни в какую.

Comment: В большинстве редакторов это уже есть либо добавляется плагинами. Попробуйте Netbeans, Eclipse и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый лучший редактор, который я когда либо встречал для PHP под Windows, не требующей практически никакой настройки (за исключением подсветки синтаксиса по вкусу и т.д.) - [NuSphere PhpED](http://www.nusphere.com/download.php.ide.htm). Однако он платный, но я думаю для русского человека это не проблема ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver cs4 - самое то, и подсказки и быстрый набор переменных и суперглобальные массивы, всё есть.

Comment: Dreamweaver cs4 нету, только cs3. Но сколько там ни тыкал, не мог найти опцию, которая отображала бы ошибки синтаксиса.

Answer (score 1):

Взгляните на PHPEclipse: [как PHPEclipse соотносится с другими редакторами PHP](http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/General/HowDoesPHPEclipseCompareWithOtherPHPEditors)?

> Syntax Coloring -           Yes
> Brackets Matching -         Yes
> Code folding -              Yes
> Code Completion -           Yes
> Parameter hints -           Yes
> Mark Occurrences -          Yes
> Hover Tooltips -            Yes
> PHP Manual integration -    Yes
> Code templates -            Yes

Answer (score 1):

phpDesigner - мой выбор. На мой взгляд самое лучшее средство.